# Javascript: Video starts with delay when started at certain position

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to display a video on a page which starts at a certain position (e.g., 10 seconds). I have found a way to program this with the code below.
My problem is that it takes the browser several seconds to start the video. As far as I have read, the browser needs to load the duration of the video before it can play it at the certain position.

Is there some way to start the video immediately without any delay?

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<video style="display:block; margin: 0 auto;" width="512" height="288" id="vid1" autoplay>
 <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" /> 
 <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 10 ;}, false)
```

I would be very thankful for every hint!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I won't have enough have the reputation to comment so posting as an answer.

Have you tried to put ??

```
document.getElementById("vid1").load();
```

This load() method is used to load/update the video.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
So do I have to add it to the code like this?

`document.getElementById("vid1").load();
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = 10 ;}, false)`

Comment: I don't have the entire code... if you put this on js-fiddle then I can check this